# Illegal start of type when try to run animation and SharedPreference together

Tags: java, android

I am new in android and now i am creating a simple login application but when i try to run the animation and SharedPreference together i am getting an error illegal start of type etc. but when i remove the of SharedPreference it works well.
I can't figure out how to solve this thing
Below is the class which showing error.

```
package com.example.spa;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static int Splash_time_out = 4000;

    private ImageView logo;
    private TextView logo_text;
    private Animation fromtop;
    private Animation frombottom;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pa_logo_imageview);
        logo_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logo_text);

        fromtop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fromtop);
        frombottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.frombottom);

        logo.setAnimation(fromtop);
        logo_text.setAnimation(frombottom);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(new UserData(MainActivity.this).getName()!="")
                {
                Intent ab = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashBoardActivity.class);
                startActivity(ab);
                finish();
            }
                else{
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login_activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
        },Splash_time_out);
    }
}
```

and here is the whole project file link if you need.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OS3liuAxLWLEfUd9jzraSI0Yoms8gicM

And below is the error

```
error: illegal start of type
```

Picture of the Error
[image]

Comment: If you line up your opening and closing braces you’ll see the problem

Comment: after lining up the braces i got the error which saying

'error: no suitable method found for show(android.app.FragmentManager,String)
method DialogFragment.show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager)
method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to FragmentTransaction)'